# Cannot forward-declare a class in a class

Tags: c++, class, syntax

I am not new to C++ but I still can't figure the syntax out, **the problem is that it's a class in another class. I only found answers for normal forward declaration**. Please don't take my code perfection too seriously here.

I tried following but nothing worked:

```
class MyClass {
public:
    class InnerClass
    {
    public:
        void boo()
        {
            foo(*this); // error: foo() is not known
        }
    };
};

void foo(MyClass::InnerClass& ref)
{
}
```

or

```
class MyClass;
class MyClass::InnerClass; // error: incomplete type is not allowed

void foo(MyClass::InnerClass& ref)
{
}

class MyClass
{
public:
    class InnerClass
    {
    public:
        void boo()
        {
            foo(*this);
        }
    };
};
```

or

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    class InnerClass;
};

void foo(MyClass::InnerClass& ref)
{
}

class MyClass // error: redefinition of 'MyClass'
{
public:
    class InnerClass
    {
    public:
        void boo()
        {
            foo(*this);
        }
    };
};
```

Comment: To declare an inner class, the *containing class must be defined*. So you can do `class MyClass{ public: class Inner;};`  then (redundantly) `class MyClass::Inner;` to declare the inner class without defining it and `class MyClass::Inner {};` to define it [I've left out your class members]. With only a declaration of `MyClass` (i.e. not a definition - so `MyClass` is formally an incomplete type) `MyClass::Inner` cannot be declared. Also, all definitions of all classes must be identical, so you can't have one definition of `MyClass` that does not declare `Inner` and another that does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define `MyClass::InnerClass:boo()` after `foo` is defined.

```
class MyClass {
public:
    class InnerClass
    {
    public:
        void boo();
    };
};

void foo(MyClass::InnerClass& ref)
{
}

void MyClass::InnerClass::boo() {
    foo(*this); 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple way is to declare the function before the inner class definition like

```
class MyClass {
public:
    class InnerClass;
};

void foo(MyClass::InnerClass& ref);

class MyClass::InnerClass {
 public:
    void boo()
    {
        foo(*this);
    }
};

void foo(MyClass::InnerClass& ref)
{
}
```

Comment: I have tried that

Comment: @MooingDuck MyClass is defined once.

Comment: @deanqx There were typos that I have upodated.

Comment: Okay I see, your solution should work too thanks